# Cubic interpolation with derivatives in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

A recent immigrant to Python and scientific computing with Python. This is a question to avoid any duplication of code that might already exist.

I have a field that is sampled as a function of x and y in a regular grid. I would want to interpolate the data to obtain not only the value of the field at any point on the grid, but also the first and second derivatives. If I interpolate it with bicubic interpolation using interp2d, I can obtain the value of the field.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to obtain the first and second derivatives of the field using an EXISTING numpy or scipy function?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [numpy.diff](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) ?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html

Comment: While `UnivariateSpine` has a method to return a derivative, for a 2D spline interpolation, I'd guess your best bet at the moment is to grab the coefficients via the `get_coeffs` and take it from there.

Comment: @mmgp numpy.diff is something that I considered but I didn't have option of choosing forward, backward or central differences.

Comment: @MrE numpy.gradient would probably work fine as well.

Comment: @Zhenya That should serve my purpose. Computing the derivatives from the coefficients is just a polynomial evaluation with the appropriate weights.

Thank y'all for responding!

Comment: @MrE you could post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 3):

The [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html) method has options `dx` and `dy` to evaluate higher derivatives at point (at least since version 0.14.0).