# Differentiate a 2d cubic spline in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, interpolation, numerical-methods, spline

I'm using interpolate.interp2d() to fit a 2-D spline over a function. How can I get the first derivative of the spline w.r.t. each of the dependent variables? Here is my code so far, Z are the descrete points on a mesh-grid that I have

```
from scipy import interpolate
YY, XX = np.meshgrid(Y, X)
f = interpolate.interp2d(AA, XX, Z, kind='cubic')
```

So, I need df/dx and df/dy. Note also that my Y-grid is not evenly spaced. I guess I can numerically differentiate Z and then fit a new spline, but it seemed like too much hassle. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Can you include some extra lines with typical (short) values for `X`, `Y`, `AA` and `Z` so this code runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate the output of `interp2d` by using the function [`bisplev`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplev.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplev) on the `tck` property of the interpolant with the optional arguments `dx` and `dy`.

If you've got some meshed data which you've interpolated:

```py
X = np.arange(5.)

Y = np.arange(6., 11)
Y[0] = 4  # Demonstrate an irregular mesh
YY, XX = np.meshgrid(Y, X)
Z = np.sin(XX*2*np.pi/5 + YY*YY*2*np.pi/11)

f = sp.interpolate.interp2d(XX, YY, Z, kind='cubic')

xt = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max())
yt = np.linspace(Y.min(), Y.max())
```

then you can access the appropriate structure for `bisplev` as `f.tck`: the partial derivative of `f` with respect to `x` can be evaluated as

```py
Z_x = sp.interpolate.bisplev(xt, yt, f.tck, dx=1, dy=0)
```

**Edit**: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29415934/5358968), it looks like the [result of `interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html) can itself take the optional arguments of `dx` and `dy`:

```py
Z_x = f(xt, yt, dx=1, dy=0)
```