# Partial derivatives of a function found using interp2d in python/sagemath

Tags: python, numerical-methods, sage

I have a function of two variables, R(t,r), that has been constructed using a list of values for R, t, and r. This function cannot be written down, the values are found from solving a differential equation (d R(t,r)/dt). I require to take the derivatives of the function, in particular, I need
dR(t,r)/dr, d^2R(t,r)/drdt. I have tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608484/differentiate-a-2d-cubic-spline-in-python) to do this, but I cannot seem to get an answer that makes sense. (note that all derivatives should be partials). Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

my current code. I understand getting anything to work without the `Rdata' file is impossible but the file itself is 160x1001. Really, any data could be made up to get the rest to work. Z_t does not return answers that seem like the derivative of my original function based on what I know, therefore, I know it is not differentiating my function as I'd expect.

If there are numerical routines for using the array of data I do not mind, I simply need some way of figuring out the derivatives.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

data = np.loadtxt('Rdata.txt')
rvals = np.linspace(1,160,160)
tvals = np.linspace(0,1000,1001)

f = interpolate.interp2d(tvals, rvals, data)

Z_t = interpolate.bisplev(tvals, rvals, f.tck, dx=0.8, dy=0)
```

Comment: Please show a working piece of code you wrote yet and give specific error messages or details you would like help about.
See MRE here: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Malo I have edited my question. `data' could be any array if one is trying to get this to work.

Comment: Suggestion: provide an 8 by 8 array extracted from your 160 by 1000 array (take the first 8 values for `r` and `t`). Optionally, provide the complete `Rdata.txt` as a link to pastebin or similar).